# How to connect thingsboard cloud in python without using mqtt connector?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-socketio, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

Note : should not use mqtt connector.

Please guide me how to connect to thingsboard cloud by using python without mqtt connector?
I've been doing R & D for 2 weeks but I didn't find any help over the internet.

Can someone write a custom connector to connect to the thingsboard ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use HTTP instead of MQTT to send your data via Python scripts. There are several modules like the *requests* or *urllib3* available for that purpose.

Since you are using ThingsBoard Cloud there are two possible ways to send the data to ThingsBoard via HTTP:

- via HTTP Integration: https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/integrations/http/
- via HTTP Device API: https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/reference/http-api/